# select into outfile permission denied on windows

Tags: mysql, into-outfile

I am trying to run a select into outfile command from mysql 5.6 command line (mysql user : root) on windows 8 and I get a permission denied error.

The following is the error:
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\project\\output.txt' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

The following is the command that i am trying to execute through mysql command line:
mysql>select * from contractor_info into outfile "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\project\\output.txt";

I want to save a copy of table in the project folder.

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` in MySQL is handled server-side, and services on Windows generally run in restricted accounts that aren't allowed to user profile folders. You'll need to pick a different location that the account the MySQL server is running under is allowed to write to. Or, as the manual points out, you can do something like `mysql -e "SELECT ..." > file_name` to have the file I/O handled client-side.